# Get specific ArrayList item

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public static ArrayList mainList = someList;
```

How can I get a specific item from this `ArrayList`? `mainList[3]`?

Comment: New to Java, wanted to know how to access an ArrayList element, Googled it, first result was this question. Got what I needed in a few seconds.

Comment: JavaDoc is the documentation for Java, it contains all Objects and it's methods

Comment: it's a bit of an easy question, but SO posts always come up first on Google and therefore we have all of these upvotes.

Comment: JavaDoc is > 600 lines of clutter with respect to this question so referring to it is inefficient.

Comment: Stackoverflow questions I always find are easier to understand and comprehend as well as more concise compared to javadoc or online tutorials.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

As many have already told you:

```
mainList.get(3);
```

Be sure to check the [ArrayList Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Also, be careful with the arrays indices: in Java, the first element is at index `0`. So if you are trying to get the third element, your solution would be `mainList.get(2);`

Answer (score 40):

Time to familiarize yourself with the `ArrayList` API and more:

[`ArrayList` at Java 6 API Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html?is-external=true)

For your immediate question:

`mainList.get(3);`

Answer (score 14):

```
mainList.get(list_index)
```

Comment: Presumably this was downvoted given the lack of explanation or link to where this function is documented, or perhaps just because it's (by far) the worst of (now) 6 answers which all say essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

```
mainList.get(3);
```

For future reference, you should refer to the Java API for these types of questions:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

It's a useful thing!

Answer (score 5):

We print the value using mainList.get(index) where index starts with '0'.
For Example: mainList.get(2) prints the 3rd element in the list.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply get your answer from ArrayList [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) doc.

Please always refer API documentation .. it helps

Your call will looklike following :

```
mainList.get(3);
```

Here is simple tutorial for understanding ArrayList with Basics :) :

http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java/java-arraylist-tutorial.html

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
ArrayListname.get(index);
```

Where `index` is the position in the index and `ArrayListname` is the name of the Arraylist as in your case is mainList.

Answer (score -2):

I have been using the ArrayListAdapter to dynamically put in the entries into the respective fields ;
**This can be useful , for future queries**

```
 AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
```

And then , you can fetch any arraylist item as below :

```
arrayListName(info.position);
```