# Get single item from List<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: java, android, list, hashmap

I am modifying someone else code.
I have a variable of type `List<HashMap<String, String>>`

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> lst
```

I tried to use get the item single value by using

```
lst[0,1]
lst[0][1]
lst.get(0)[1]
lst.get(0)(1)
lst.get(0)("ID")
```

but non works.

how to get a single item value?

```
    List<HashMap<String, String>> lst = null;

    try{
        lst = myXmlParser.detparse(reader);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: use `list.get(index);` it will return you an object of type `HashMap<String,String>` `index` here is an `int` of your choice.

Comment: Should be `List<Map<String, String>> lst`

Comment: I used list.get(index) but it will not return a single value it will return a list of 4 items

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: get specific ArrayList item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920602/java-get-specific-arraylist-item)

Comment: Not sure what the code producing the List<HashMap<String,String>> by getparse is meant to say in connection with the question "how to get a single item".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the documentation of [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (respective [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)) to see how to use them.

Since your `List` contains `Map` you'll have to get a `Map` using the `List` operations and then get the elements from that `Map` using the `Map` operations:

```
HashMap<String, String> firstMap = lst.get(0);
String someEntry = firstMap.get("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, String> firstEntryInList = list.get(0);
```

Where '0' is the index.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using index of list...

```
HashMap<String, String> entry = lst.get(0);
```

Comment: @DownVoter, Can it be commented, why to down vote? To return an element from a list using indexes - use get(index) is the suggestion and its appropriate to the question.

Comment: I think that a rather weird one was downvoting each and every answer on this Q. I got credited +8, which looks like one up and one down, others may have experienced similar.

Answer (score 0):

Accessor methods must be applied from outer to inner. If you have a

```
List<Whatever> lst
```

you use

```
lst.get(0)
```

to retrieve the first element in the list. If Whatever is in turn an aggregate, you apply the appropriate accessor on the returned value:

```
List<Map<String,String>> lst
```

and to get the string that's mapped via "somekey":

```
lst.get(0).get("somekey")
```

Now, this will get you a String, and this has accessors, too, eg. for accessing a single character:

```
lst.get(0).get("somekey").charAt(0)
```

This is "the first character of the string mapped with key "somekey" in the first hash map of the list lst".