# Noob issue. I have doubles stored in ArrayList. Having difficulty adding their total to a single double variable.

Tags: java

Simply put, the program is find the average value of doubles entered until a negative number is entered. I'm just receiving an error at the kk += numbers[z];

```
    double kk = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a series of numbers; entering a negative number will quit the program.");
    System.out.println("The resulting average value will be returned");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Double> numbers =  new ArrayList<>();

    while (scan.hasNextDouble()){
        if (scan.nextDouble() >= 0)
            numbers.add(scan.nextDouble());
        else
            System.exit(0);
    }

    for (int z = 0; z < numbers.length; z++){
        kk += numbers[z];
        double ave = kk / numbers.length;
    }
    System.out.println(ave);
```

Comment: Please click "edit" under your post and add the exact error message.

Comment: You want numbers.get (z). You can't index a List in Java

Comment: Duplicate of [Get specific ArrayList item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920602/get-specific-arraylist-item) and [How can I get the size of an array, a Collection, or a String in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730092/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-a-collection-or-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

`List` doesn't have a `length` property, nor can you access values from it like an array, instead you need to use `size()` and `get(int)`

You should also declare `ave` outside of the context of the `for-loop`

```
for (int z = 0; z < numbers.size(); z++){
    kk += numbers.get(z);
}
double ave = kk / numbers.size();
System.out.println(ave);
```

Take a look at the [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

Next, you don't want to use `System.exit` to exit a loop, you probably want to use `break` instead

```
while (scan.hasNextDouble()){
    if (scan.nextDouble() >= 0)
        numbers.add(scan.nextDouble());
    else break;
}
```

But I might approach it slightly differently...

```
    double kk = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a series of numbers; entering a negative number will quit the program.");
    System.out.println("The resulting average value will be returned");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    boolean done = false;
    do {
        String value = scan.nextLine();
        try {
            double number = Double.parseDouble(value);
            if (number > 0) {
                numbers.add(number);
            } else {
                done = true;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            System.out.println(value + " is not a valid double");
        }
    } while (!done);

    for (int z = 0; z < numbers.size(); z++) {
        kk += numbers.get(z);
    }
    double ave = kk / numbers.size();
    System.out.println(ave);
```

Comment: or he could use the collection-based for loop ;)

Comment: You've been so incredibly helpful. All of you actually. Thank you.

Comment: @LittleChild I thought that to, but I though some baby steps might be more suitable