# No zero item in Java ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

When developing an Android App I faced with the situation when there is no element in non-empty Java ArrayList with zero index. The reason of the problem is somehow connected with the fact that I sometimes delete the zero-indexed items with **list.remove(0)** method when the list is non-empty. Nevertheless the specification on the remove method says that it "Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices)". So I can't understand what is the reason of situations (it happens sometimes) when I  get a non-empty list with no zero element (the first element has index 1). I can see no zero element both by getting an NullPointerException on **list.get(0)** and by seeing ArrayList content in Android Studio Debugger.

[Debugging screenshot - ArrayList's shapshot with no zero item in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAAfr.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the code and tell us what line of it gets the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get specific ArrayList item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920602/get-specific-arraylist-item)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I call list.get(0) to get the zero-indexed element

Answer (score 0):

The first element in a not empty list [has always index 0](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/List.html). As stated by documentation:

> Lists (like Java arrays) are zero based

What you see in your debugging screenshot is simply a method of visualization for elements presents in the list. What is called 1 is not the index, but the position. So 1 stay for first element.

Comment: But when I try to call list.get(0) I get exception in this case where 0 is really supposed to be the index. I would like to remind that the situation with no 0-element happens rarely (sometimes, not every time). In common case (normal case) just after calling list.remove(0) we get the list shifted and starting with 0-element and thus we can call get(0) but sometimes happens what was described above.

Comment: Check size of list calling list.size(). If 0th element doesn't exists the list is empty.